Science fiction movie with one or more aliens on Earth and a puppet of a monster that can turn into an actual monster
I'm fairly certain that I watched this movie as a child (late 80s, maybe early 90s).
There are one or a few aliens in it. The plot takes place on Earth. One of the aliens has a puppet of a "monster" that can turn into an actual "monster". In one scene, a finger gets chopped off and lands in a meat grinder.
Sorry, that's all. It's a VERY faint memory.

Hmmm. Some XTRO (1982) vibes (aliens, puppet, monster) with this one.

Probably the same film as Scifi Movie: Alien family comes to Earth and causes chaos.

"The Wiz" from 1978, based on "The Wizard of Oz", has a scene wherein a subway peddler's puppets grow to monstrous size. There are no aliens in the film, but lots of weird Oz characters. Another possibility is "Trick or Treat", a heavy metal horror film from 1986, in which the evil rock star has a demonic sidekick, but I don't know if the demon's 'at rest' form is as a puppet or a tattoo. Again, no aliens.

This is Visitors from the Arkana Galaxy (1981).
The motif is a story-within-a-story. Notably the alien family's child has a toy which becomes a gigantic monster.

As the city finds out about the aliens, a group of scuba divers goes
to the island armed with harpoons, but are attacked by Targo, who
shoots laser rays from his eyes. This greatly increases the public
interest in the aliens—tourists flock en masse to the island, arriving
naked to convince the aliens they mean no harm. However, they find the
island empty. Toni also stalks Robert and the aliens with a camera, to
no avail. Robert is fired from his job, and coming home, he finds the
aliens nested there. He is fascinated by Andra and touches her skin,
but a jealous Biba bursts into the room, swearing at Andra. Targo
places a small Mumu in Biba's bag, which she brings home after dumping
Robert in her fury. Back at her home, Mumu grows in size, but while he
is actually peaceful, his monstrous appearance frightens Biba's
flatmates, who panickedly attack it, only to die from the spray of its
poisonous blood. As Mumu makes his way downstairs, he is blinded by
the flash of Toni's camera, bursts in on a wedding feast and kills
almost all attendees after they try to attack him.




You can watch it online below. I've time-stamped the scene with the meat grinder.




OMFG. That's gotta be it. Forgot to mention that I'm from Germany so the movie most definitely must have been dubbed when I watched it.
But this clearly looks like it. Even has the gold aliens which I didn't even remember until now.
Thank you so much!!

@bitfrickler - You're very welcome
